# What is causing segmentation fault in append Node function in doubly linked list?

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, append, doubly-linked-list

My doubly linked list implementation is as follows that each node holds an array of four values

```
#define EMPTYNODE 0

struct node {
short data[4]; // pay attention
struct node* next;
struct node* prev;
};

typedef struct node nodeQ_t;

typedef enum{
   LIST_FALSE = 0,
   LIST_TRUE = 1,
} status_t;

nodeQ_t* createNode(short values[4]){

    nodeQ_t* node = (nodeQ_t*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    for(int i=0; i < 4; i++){
       node->data[i] = values[i];
     }

   node->next = EMPTYNODE;
   node->prev = EMPTYNODE;
   return node;
}
```

now I am trying to write append function in a way that I supply it head and a node created in createNode function so that it would append it to the list.... but it creates a segmentation fault...

```
status_t appendNode(nodeQ_t* head, nodeQ_t* newNode){
if(head == EMPTYNODE || newNode == EMPTYNODE){
    return LIST_FALSE;
};

nodeQ_t* currentNode = head;

while(currentNode != EMPTYNODE){
    if(currentNode->next == EMPTYNODE){ //it means that current node is tail
        currentNode->next = newNode;  //segmenttion fault arises at exactly this line 
        newNode->prev = currentNode;
    }
    currentNode = currentNode->next;
}
return LIST_TRUE;
}
```

please let me know what is the reason for that...
for your reference my main function is

```
int main(){
  short array[4] = {1,2,3,4};

  nodeQ_t* head  = createNode(array);

  printList(head);


  short array2[4] = {5,6,7,8};

  nodeQ_t* newNode = createNode(array2);

  appendNode(head, newNode);


  printList(head);



  return 0;

}
```

if you need any further information or explanation for anything please do let me know

Comment: `break` out of your `while` loop once insertion succeeds.

Comment: I think your problem is here: ```(nodeQ_t*)malloc(sizeof(node))```. That should be ```sizeof(*node)```. ```node``` is a pointer so you're allocating bytes for the size of the pointer, not the size of the struct ```node``` points to.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: I'm not saying the return from ```malloc``` isn't a pointer. I'm saying ```sizeof(node)``` is allocating just 4 or 8 bytes (whatever the size of a pointer is) when the correct thing to do is allocate ```*node``` bytes, the size of the struct. See @Johnny Mopp's answer below.

Comment: @sj95126: Sorry, ambiguous use of the identifier `node` here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to `break` out of the loop once you've reached the end:

```
while(currentNode != EMPTYNODE) {
    if (currentNode->next == EMPTYNODE) {
        currentNode->next = newNode;
        newNode->prev = currentNode;
        // need a break here
    }
    currentNode = currentNode->next;
    // When at the end of the list the 1st time through, 
    // currentNode is the newly created node because you have
    //     currentNode->next = newNode
    // then
    //     currentNode = currentNode->next
    // On the next iteration, the new node next ends up getting pointed to itself 
    // since on that iteration newNode and currentNode are the same.
    // and you end up with an infinite loop.
}
```

Another option is to loop on `currentNode->next`:

```
while (currentNode->next) {
    currentNode = currentNode->next;
}
currentNode->next = newNode;
newNode->prev = currentNode;
```

I should note that this works because you previously ensured that `currentNode` is not `NULL`.

Also, your allocation here is wrong:

```
nodeQ_t* node = (nodeQ_t*)malloc(sizeof(node));
```

Because `node` is a pointer and `sizeof(node)` is the size of a pointer, not the size of `struct node`. Should be

```
nodeQ_t* node = (nodeQ_t*)malloc(sizeof(*node));
```

Answer (score 0):

You end up in endless loop:

```
while(currentNode != EMPTYNODE){
    if(currentNode->next == EMPTYNODE){ //it means that current node is tail
        currentNode->next = newNode;  //segmenttion fault arises at exactly this line 
        newNode->prev = currentNode;
    }
```

`currentNode` will always be different than `EMPTYNODE`.
Add break or return after adding new element:

```
while(currentNode != EMPTYNODE){
    if(currentNode->next == EMPTYNODE){ //it means that current node is tail
        currentNode->next = newNode;  //segmenttion fault arises at exactly this line 
        newNode->prev = currentNode;
        return LIST_TRUE;
    }
```